# Cant activate link that created dynamically with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i have a button that creates a new page and inserts it to the dom. 
When i click the new button nothing happens. I want the event handler to be fired again.
any suggestions ?

```
   $("a").on("click", function () {
       var html = "";
       html += '<div data-role="page" data-url="newpage" data-theme="e" id="test" data-prefetch="true">' +
           '<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="inline">' +
           '<h3>"dynamic page"</h3>' +
           '</div>' +
           '<div data-role="content" data-theme="a" class="dynamicPage">' +
           ' <a href="#" data-role="button" id="workIT"   > Save </a>' +
           '</div></div>';
       $(html).appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
       $("#test").trigger('create');

       $.mobile.changePage("#test");
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put it in the `pageinit` event of the page (`div` with `[data-role=page]`) where the button is. This way you'll bind the event when the page is ready and is in DOM.
2. Use event delegation to bind the `click` to the anchor tag. The page should be used as the parent, so when the click happens on an `a` tag, the tag will go serach for the event in the `div` with `[data-role=page]`.
3. Use `preventDefault` to stop the `a` from using the `href` tag to redirect.
4. Remove `trigger("create")` - unnecessary because jQM takes care of this during page transition.

Here's the code :

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#mypage", function () {
    var $page = $(this);
    $(this).on("click", "a", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //your code 
         html += '<div data-role="page" data-url="newpage" data-theme="e" id="test" data-prefetch="true">' +
        '<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="inline">' +
        '<h3>"dynamic page"</h3>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div data-role="content" data-theme="a" class="dynamicPage">' +
        ' <a href="#" data-role="button" id="workIT"   > Save </a>' +
        '</div></div>';
      $(html).appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
      $.mobile.changePage("#test");
    });
});
```

**If you want to be able to use the save button of the dynamic page**, add a `pageinit` event for that page. In your case thats gonna be `#test` :

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#test", function () {
   //event delegation - binds the click to the <a> tags inside the page #test
    $(this).on("click", "a", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Saved!");
    });
});
```

(Updated) Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/V6QG2/

**A more generic `pageinit` :**

```
 $(document).on("pageinit", "[data-role=page]", function() {
   //your code
 });
```

Comment: when i click on the save button' i want to crate a new page, how do i do it ?

Comment: @user2625384 you mean you want to save your created page or create yet another page?

Comment: i want to be able to do some actions when i click on the save button.

Comment: it looks great but what if i make several pages that i don't know their id - for example i am getting the information from web server, and there is no way to get the id. can i have generic pageinit for all the pages ??

Comment: are you gonna have generic buttons inside them?

Comment: only two - back or save , if save so collect all the data and send it to the server

Comment: it seems the solution, last question. how can i combine all the code that i have inside the document.ready with the document.on(pageinit).

Comment: i agree, i was sure its a small problem - only to add the element to the dom and then to use it. when i see the solution, it makes the problem a bit bigger. on my document.ready i have a connection to the server ( ajax) ,update the listview with the response and then the user selects an item and receive a dynamic form .

Comment: uve got only two buttons right? add classes to those buttons and bind it to `click` the way ive bound in the answer..

Comment: @user2625384 mail me your code, il try to reformat it for you .. hpkrishna07@gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PMrDn/55/

### Code

You want to use it like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "a",function () {
   var html = "";
   html += '<div data-role="page" data-url="newpage" data-theme="e" id="test" data-prefetch="true">' +
       '<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="inline">' +
       '<h3>"dynamic page"</h3>' +
       '</div>' +
       '<div data-role="content" data-theme="a" class="dynamicPage">' +
       ' <a href="#" data-role="button" id="workIT"   > Save </a>' +
       '</div></div>';
   $(html).appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);

   $.mobile.changePage("#test");
})
```

### Explanation

- This is called deleyd event binding. Basically it don't care if button is a part of the DOM or not. Event will be bound to the document object and it will propagate when correct element is found in the DOM.
- Second thing, don't bind this just to a a tag, I bet you have more then one button. Use class name or id instead.
- Third thing, you don't need this line:

  ```
  $("#test").trigger('create');
  ```

  jQuery Mobile will automatically style your page during the page transition. Just look at my working example.
- Last thing, there could be another problem. If you are using several HTML pages and this javascript is placed inside a HEAD. In this case read this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Act on the event
    });
```